# FIR / IIR and Wavelets

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, wavelet

I am a self-learner of DSP by reading various books. I have accomplished basic understanding of Signals - CT and DT and a few transforms. I recently started to learn FIR / IIR Filters.

The part that I cannot understand is that they are termed as 'Filters' which for me logically means blocking / allowing from a threshold value - ex. lower values would be passed higher would be filtered or removed. So if we have a low pass filter - it would lead us to remove high values from a sequence and vice versa for high pass filters - is my understanding correct?

Like HPF (High Pass Filter):

```
x(n)={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

Set threshold as **>=5** so output sequence would be {5,6,7,8,9}

OK but the document states FIR / IIR about :

> Finite Impulse Response (FIR) : this type of filter gives a finite
>   number of nonzero outputs (response) to an impulse function input. It
>   does not use feed-back.

While

> Infinite Impulse Response (IIR) : this type of filter uses feed-back,
>   so it could have an infinite number of nonzero outputs (response) to
>   an impulse function input.

Now I cannot understand what FIR / IIR has to do with my concept of filters - allow / block high / low values. Where does the question of Feedback comes here?

Similarly for wavelets -

> We call an octave a level of resolution, where each octave can be
>   envisioned as a pair of FIR filters, at least for the one-dimensional
>   case. One filter of the analysis (wavelet transform) pair is a lowpass
>   filter (LPF), while the other is a highpass filter (HPF). Each filter
>   has a down-sampler after it, to make the transform efficient.  For
>   example, a simple lowpass filter may have coefficients {1/2,1/2},
>   producing outputs (x[n] + x[n - 1])/2, which is clearly the average of
>   two samples. A corresponding simple highpass filter would have
>   coefficients {1/2,-1/2}, producing outputs (x[n] - x[n - 1])/2, half
>   the difference of the samples.

I am not able to get the concept of how and why here equation : (x[n] + x[n - 1])/2 and (x[n] - x[n - 1])/2 is being referred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[High pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter) and [Low pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter) in signal processing refer to a system which respectively passes high-*frequency* and low-*frequency* contents (equivalently respectively blocks low-*frequency* and high-*frequency* contents) from the signal, not low/high *values*.

So for example, given a sequence which is the sum of a constant value (low-frequency component) and a more rapidly varying alternating values (high-frequency component):

```
x(n) = {0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, ...}
```

The output of a low-pass filter computing `y[n] = (x[n] + x[n-1])/2` would look like:

```
y(n) = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...}
```

Keeping only the low-frequency constant value.

Similarly, the output of a high-pass filter computing `y[n] = (x[n] - x[n-1])/2` would look like:

```
y(n) = {1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, ...}
```

This time keeping only the high-frequency content of the signal (the alternating values).

Now, this 'selection' of low-frequency and high-frequency component can often be achieved as the solution to [difference equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) (a mathematical relation which combines various input and output samples). FIR and IIR are specific categorisations of those filters, which are distinguished by the dependency on previous output samples (eg. `y[n-1]`) in the difference equation (hence the notion of feedback). For example, a simple IIR low-pass filter (with different characteristics as the previous FIR low-pass filter example) could be implemented as the difference equation:

```
y[n] = 0.9*y[n-1] + 0.1*x[n];
```

Where the current output sample `y[n]` is expressed in terms of the previous output `y[n-1]`.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation. It clarifies my doubts and misunderstanding